# Memory leak JQuery - all browsers

Tags: memory-leaks, event-handling, settimeout, jquery-1.3, multiple-browsers

I am using jquery in my web page. I see a lot of memory leak happening and after a while the whole browser grinds to a halt. I used the sieve tool and noticed that there is a contsant increase in the no. of DOM elements, everytime by a no. of 4.

Am I doing something wrong in the way I have associated events?
Or is it because I am using setTimeout to redraw my app every X seconds?

Event association:

$('.bir_Names').click(showNames);
The selector $('.bir_Names') evelautes to a set of some 300 elements each of which call the function on click.

setTimeout
Every X mins I remove every single HTML element in the app and rebind fresh data and associate the events. I use jquery remove() to delete elements. have tried innerHTML = '' and empty() also.

I see a jump of nearly 30-40 MB for every redraw and Sieve indicates that none of the deleted nodes are actually removed.

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated. This thing is driving me nuts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which browser, but some googling seems to indicate that this is a known problem with IE. Here's one potential workaround:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/possible-memory-leak-in-remove-and-empty

Note that that's referring to a 1.2.x release of jQuery. Before you do anything, make sure you are running the latest 1.6.x release to first see if the defect has already been fixed within jQuery.

[EDIT] ack...you DO state your browsers...'all'...so maybe disregard that first link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I notice this problem in all browsers IE6/7/8, FF, Safari. I have tried including the latest version of jquery as well, but the problem persists. Not sure if there is something fundamentally worng in the way I have associated the events.